# Django 1.8: NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

To begin with, this code works on my local test environment, but fails to work on our staging environment.

The error I am getting is-

```
Reverse for 'myaccounttempid' with arguments '('---URL_SAFE_BASE64_HASH_HERE---',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

In My urls.py, I have

```
url(r'^accounts/my-account/temporary-id/(?P<member_id>[A-Za-z0-9=_\-]+)/$', my_account_temporary_id,
    name='myaccounttempid'),
```

In My Template, I have

```
<a href="{% url 'myaccounttempid' member.member_id|encode_for_url %}">Link</a>
```

In models.py, I have

```
def my_account_temporary_id(request, member_id):
    member_id = decode_value_from_url(member_id)
```

I have tried passing the member ID hash in with *args, and **kwargs while debugging.  This seems like something that should be simple... what am I missing?

---

Here is the code for the function the cutom template tag encode_for_url calls

```
def encode_value_for_url(original_value):
    """First base 64 encodes a value, cryptographically signs it and then base 64 encodes it again."""
    signer = Signer()
    encoded_data = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(original_value)
    signed_data = signer.sign(encoded_data)

    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signed_data)
```

Comment: What is the filter `encode_for_url` returning?

Comment: encode_for_url is returning the url safe base64 string that actually goes to the function.

Comment: Are you using a namespace to include urls?

Comment: There are no namespaces for the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ignoring my function because I was using Reportlab, and Reportlab wasn't installed on the Staging server.  Once I put that up, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the hyphen with a backslash

```
[A-Za-z0-9=\-_]
```

Or you can move it to the end of the group

```
[A-Za-z0-9=_-]`.
```

At the moment, `=-_` is treated as the range from `=` to `_`, which does not actually include `-`.

Comment: I should have noticed that basic RegEx no no.  I will adjust my code above appropriately, but this still didn't do the trick.  It still runs on my local machine, but not on the staging server.  Only configuration difference I can see is the Python version - On my local machine, I have 2.7.10 and the server has 2.7.3